# Chemical inhibition of fertilization in plants

Tags: molecular-biology, botany, plant-physiology, agriculture

Are there any chemical compounds that inhibit fertilization in plants after gametogenesis? Simply put, I am talking about spermicide or emergency contraception for plants.

Specifically, I am searching for a compound that will inhibit fertilization of an ovum when a pollen grain has already contacted the stigma. This compound may be effective before or after the pollen tube has formed, but ideally before zygogenesis. Although, I am also interested in compounds that prevent maturation of the zygote (basically an abortive action).

The compound is effective when applied externally to the plant (via a liquid spray, for example). Alternatively, it could be absorbed via roots or some other route.

The compound may be a small-molecule or macro-molecule.